# Error in UseRelationship function

Tags: ssas, dax

I'm here again. I'm developing an example of tabular model on Analysis Services and I've an error that I'm not able to solve.

This is my tables diagram just now:

[image]

The relevant tables are MARCHAMOS, ARFABRI and DimFecha (the top ones). MARCHAMOS and ARFABRI are joined by 2 relationships (2 fields of MARCHAMOS could be paired with 1 field of ARFABRI (depends of the situation)).

Now I'm trying to get a measure with the following DAX query:

```
UnidadesFrescosCompradas:= countx(
calculatetable(
    filter(
        marchamos; 
        not isempty (relatedtable('ARFABRI'))
    );
    MID(MARCHAMOS[REGIS03]; 1; 1) = "1";
    TIPOS_COCHINILLO[GRUPO]=0;
    userelationship(MARCHAMOS[REGIS28];ARFABRI[ARFA01]);
    userelationship(ARFABRI[ARFA06]; DimFecha[Fecha])

);
[regis01])
```

As you can see, I'm telling the system the relationships that it must use (one of them is from MARCHAMOS to ARFABRI and the other one is from ARFABRI to DimFecha). But I get this error:

[image]

If I remove the "userelationship(ARFABRI[ARFA06]; DimFecha[Fecha])" caluse of the filter, the error disappears, but the result is not correct.
I don't understand this, since both relationships are not over the same tables.

Any hint?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can USERELATIONSHIP with both active and inactive relationships. It looks like you have an ambiguity in that you have two eligible relationships for `MARCHAMOS` and `ARFABRI`.

Since the ending point column for `ARFABRI` is the same in both relationships you get the error.

Can you delete the inactive relationship?